Passing Custom Attributes to Spawned GameObjects in Unity Netcode
I created my first network application with unity netcode. I spawn bullets which appear on client site. But they have always the default configuration / default parameters are not overritten. I don’t know how to pass custom attributes to a spawned GameObject correctly. What I do is that:
            var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, rotation);
            // bullet.NetworkObject.Spawn(); // no change
            bullet.damage = bulletDamage;
            bullet.speed = bulletSpeed;
            bullet.ownerType = playerType;
            bullet.ownerPlayerNumber = playerNumber;
            bullet.origin = gameObject.GetComponent<Tower>();
            bullet.NetworkObject.Spawn();

I read that it could be relevant that I spawn the object first and set then the attributes. So I add the bullet.NetworkObject.Spawn(); behind Instantiate. No change.
Another solutions could be that I send the parameter afterwards. So after it’s spawned I send the custom variables. But this doesn’t feel like good architecture.
How can I send my bullet with the attributes?
